# how to throttle logs using awk

Tags: awk

I am having a tool which is resulting in a similar line of result sometimes. However these lines are not exactly same but can be treated as one. So I needed to check if there are five logs in a row and if there are , then print "this is a repeated log". This is needed to be done on the basics of sequence , not the content as there can be minor differences. I am trying to allow 5 individual full messages and 6th on wards should be masked as "repated"

Logs are as follow, actual logs are very long text, for simplicity used this

```
 -->echo "$x"
09:09:02 a  aa1
09:09:03 a aa2
09:09:04 a aa3
09:09:05 a aa4
09:09:06 a aa5
09:09:07 a ssf
09:09:08 a s2
09:09:09 a 243
09:09:10 a 21
09:09:11 a 12
09:09:12 a 21
09:09:13 a 32
09:09:14 a 21
09:09:15 a 12
09:09:16 b 21
09:09:17 b 12
09:09:18 b 12
09:09:19 a 12
09:09:20 a 32
09:09:21 a 32
09:09:22 a 21
09:09:23 a 11
09:09:24 a 23
09:09:25 a 32
09:09:26 a 32
09:09:27 b 21
09:09:28 b 21
09:09:29 b 1
09:09:30 b 1
09:09:31 b 32
09:09:32 b 23
09:09:33 b 21
09:09:34 b 2
09:09:35 b 1
09:09:36 b 3
09:09:37 b 4
09:09:38 b 5
09:09:39 b 6
09:09:40 b 7
09:09:41 b 8
09:09:42 c 9
09:09:43 c 0
09:09:44 c 9
09:09:45 c 8
09:09:46 c 5
```

Expected result:

```
09:09:02 a aa1
09:09:03 a aa2
09:09:04 a aa3
09:09:05 a aa4
09:09:06 a aa5
09:09:07 above message is repeated
09:09:08 above message is repeated
09:09:09 above message is repeated
09:09:10 above message is repeated
09:09:11 above message is repeated
09:09:12 above message is repeated
09:09:13 above message is repeated
09:09:14 above message is repeated
09:09:15 above message is repeated
09:09:16 b 21
09:09:17 b 12
09:09:18 b 12
09:09:19 a 12
09:09:20 a 12
09:09:21 a 32
09:09:22 a 32
09:09:23 a 21
09:09:24 above message is repeated
09:09:25 above message is repeated
09:09:26 above message is repeated
09:09:27 b 21
09:09:28 b 21
09:09:29 b 1
09:09:30 b 1
09:09:31 b 32
09:09:32 above message is repeated
09:09:33 above message is repeated
09:09:34 above message is repeated
09:09:35 above message is repeated
09:09:36 above message is repeated
09:09:37 above message is repeated
09:09:38 above message is repeated
09:09:39 above message is repeated
09:09:40 above message is repeated
09:09:41 above message is repeated
09:09:42 c 9
09:09:43 c 0
09:09:44 c 9
09:09:45 c 8
09:09:46 c 5
```

I am trying to group them in group of 5 but its not printing anything

```
echo "$x" |awk '{input=$2;next}{if(input==$2)c=c+1;if(c<=5)print $0 ;print "above message is repeated"}'
```

Comment: Not clear at all, how come lines ending with `a1.a2` etc are not same and lines like `s2,ssf` etc are getting considered as same?Please do let us know logic of it for more clear picture of your question.

Comment: Idea is to ignore anything beyond `timestamp a/b/c` . Here `a/b/c` are the key markers

Comment: Please explain about like `09:09:07 a ssf` what has repeated before it so we could print message that it is repeated, please explain it more clearly.

Comment: it is the 6th message, I am trying to allow 5 individual full messages and 6th on wards should be masked as "repated"

Comment: Are they always in continuous sequence or they could be without sequence too?

Comment: always sequence

Comment: A more sensible way would be `HH:MM:SS to HH:MM:SS Above message repeated * times`

Comment: @Tiw, thanks for nice thought, I have added solution now for this logic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP' comment Input_file's 2nd column is sorted already. Could you please try following.

```
awk '
prev!=$2{
  count=0
}
{
  ++count
}
count>5{
  print $1,"above  message is repeated....."
  next
}
1
{
  prev=$2
}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per Tiw's comments and good thought in case someone need to print from which timings to which timings we need the count of repetitions then try following.

```
awk '
prev!=$2 && prev{
    if(count>5){
      print "Time stamp FROM " start " to " prev_time " Above message repeated " value_count " times."
    }
    count=value_count=start=prev_time=""
}
{
    ++count
}
{
    prev=$2
    prev_time=$1
}
count>5{
    start=start?start:$1
    value_count++
    next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output for above code will be as follows.

```
09:09:02 a  aa1
09:09:03 a aa2
09:09:04 a aa3
09:09:05 a aa4
09:09:06 a aa5
Time stamp FROM 09:09:07 to 09:09:15 Above message repeated 9 times.
09:09:16 b 21
09:09:17 b 12
09:09:18 b 12
09:09:19 a 12
09:09:20 a 32
09:09:21 a 32
09:09:22 a 21
09:09:23 a 11
Time stamp FROM 09:09:24 to 09:09:26 Above message repeated 3 times.
09:09:27 b 21
09:09:28 b 21
09:09:29 b 1
09:09:30 b 1
09:09:31 b 32
Time stamp FROM 09:09:32 to 09:09:41 Above message repeated 10 times.
09:09:42 c 9
09:09:43 c 0
09:09:44 c 9
09:09:45 c 8
09:09:46 c 5
```

Comment: @monk, could you please check this once and let me know then?

Comment: I did some fundamental mistakes while asking question, this worked. but requirement is different. thanks for your help. Trying another approch.

Comment: @oguzismail when I checked on online bash terminal(which I may not be able to open after 1 hour in office :) so I will not be able to check this link there), I could NOT see any first blank line, here is the link https://paiza.io/projects/cUgTep5VrgcnxwPFqinVGg?language=bash even I am not sure if this link  works after sometime or not, as of now I tried in different browsers and it is working fine.